# Javascript clicker, clicking animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I want to create an effect like the one below. I mean- when I click the cookie, a little "+1.0" appears on the screen fading out. I know how to make it only for one "+1.0", but what about multiple clicks and multiple "+1.0"'s?
 For example, animate() duration is 2000ms and I click 4times per 2000ms. How can I make it to show 4x "+1.0"'s, not only one?

http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

Comment: The duration of each separate event should not matter, as all clicks should be handled as separate events...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/Lu4of1f1/1/).

It uses `@keyframes-animation` to achieve the desired effect.

Its is not exactly what you want, but if given time this will help you to solve your problem.

Here is the snippet.

```js
var x = 0;
$("#cookie").click(function(e) {
  x++;
  $("#cookie").append('<div id="x' + x + '" hidden>+1.0</div>');
  $("#x" + x).css("top", e.clientY);
  $("#x" + x).css("left", e.clientX - 10);
  $("#x" + x).css("position", "absolute");
  $("#x" + x).css("width", "25px");
  $("#x" + x).css("height", "25px");
  $("#x" + x).css("color", "white");
  $("#x" + x).css("font-weight", "bold");
  $("#x" + x).css("animation", "GoUp 2s forwards linear");
  $("#x" + x).show();
});
```

```css
#cookie {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
@keyframes GoUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cookie">

</div>
```

Comment: That works good, thanks. But it's still not what I was looking for, because when I click 2 times, the first "+1.0" disappears...

Comment: i have updated the snippet and the  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/Lu4of1f1/1/) in the answer.Now it works like you want.